# counting frequency of values in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows

```
   DATA <- read.table(text = "col1  col2
   ATG   AT
   NA    AT1
   ATC   AT2
   ATD   AT3
   ATE   AT3
   ATF   AT4
   ATH   AT4
   ATI   AT4
   ATL   AT4", header=TRUE)
```

I used

```
   result<-data.frame(table(DATA$col2))
```

to get what I wanted

```
  ##result
  col1  col2
  1     AT
  1     AT1
  1     AT2
  2     AT3
  4     AT4
```

The problem is the second row in col1 has NA and should be counted as zero but I am unable to do that. It should be

```
       ##result
  col1  col2
  1     AT
  0     AT1
  1     AT2
  2     AT3
  4     AT4
```

Comment: `result<-data.frame(table(data$col2[!is.na(data$col1)]))`

Comment: I need the NA values to be counted as zeroes and not eliminate them as I have shown in the expected result for further computations.

Comment: @Paul if you run Barker's code, it gives your expected output, including the `0` row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dfs = read.table(text =
"col1 col2
ATG AT
NA AT1
ATC AT2
ATD AT3
ATE AT3
ATF AT4
ATH AT4
ATI AT4
ATL AT4", sep = " ", header = TRUE)

data.frame(xtabs( !is.na(col1) ~ col2, data = dfs))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your code a little:

```
result<-data.frame(table(DATA[!is.na(DATA$col1),]$col2))
result

  Var1 Freq
1   AT    1
2  AT1    0
3  AT2    1
4  AT3    2
5  AT4    4
```